# Trigger is firing on all edits not just defined cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to get edits made on a sheet to automatically send to Slack to alert people. That aspect is working great. However, instead of firing just when i have an change on a predefined range it fires on all changes no matter the tab.

here is the code im using in app script:

```
function buildReport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let data = ss.getSheetByName('Mirror').getRange("A1:B13").getValues();
  let payload = buildAlert(data);
  sendAlert(payload);
}
 
 
function buildAlert(data) {
  let totalRevenue = data[0][1];
  let revenueBreakdown = data.slice(1).map(function(row) {
    return row[0] + ": " + row[1];
  }).join("\n");
 
  let payload = {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "divider"
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": " *2021 IFL FOOTBALL DRAFT* "
        }
      },
      
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Round " + totalRevenue
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Drafted Players:"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": revenueBreakdown
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  return payload;
}
 
function sendAlert(payload) {
  const webhook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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"; //Paste your webhook URL here
  var options = {
    "method": "post", 
    "contentType": "application/json", 
    "muteHttpExceptions": true, 
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) 
  };
  
  try {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Again, i need to have the trigger fire only when changes have been made to a specific range, not the whole sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have some conditions in place to check with what range of cells is being executed before firing off anything else.

Consider something like the below code. You may want to edit to include conditions such as only one cell being edited or consider if the first row (not last) falls into the range.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const maxCol = 2;
  const maxRow = 13;

  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getLastColumn() <= maxCol && range.getLastRow() <= maxRow) {
    //Run your code.
    let data = ss.getSheetByName('Mirror').getRange("A1:B13").getValues();
    let payload = buildAlert(data);
    sendAlert(payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Im definitely a novice with code and have been able borrow code here and there. When i add the onEdit function i get  TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit Any idea why?

Comment: @ScottShimer , normally you can't run `onEdit()` function from Script editor. This is one of the special GAS functions. It fires automatically every time you edit your sheet (manually).

Comment: @YuriKhristich is correct. This error will occur only the first time you MANUALLY execute it. However, once you run it, and all permissions are enabled, this will run any time a cell is edited.

Comment: Everytime i run it it  i get the error...  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ draft.gs:5      Would it be easier if it was specific to the sheet and not a range? i  have 15 other sheets on the spreadsheet that i don't want to trigger it when i edit but any edit on "Mirror" would be fine. Again, thats for helping!

Comment: Sure you could include the sheet name. Just build that condition into the if statement. `if (range.getLastColumn() <= maxCol && range.getLastRow() <= maxRow && range.getSheet().getName()=="Mirror")`

Comment: That error you're getting is still related to you MANUALLY triggering the procedure. It will work if it's triggered automatically (i.e. go change a cell in your spreadsheet, not from the editor).